# How to Update multiple Records in Salesforce Object using Cloud pages

Tags: javascript, salesforce, exacttarget, ampscript

I am trying to update multiple rows in Salesforce opportunities object on the same field but with different values. even thought I am able to display all those rows and created a input field for all of them, I cannot come up with the solution on how to update those entered values for each rows to salesforce records

Comment: Please update your question to include a code sample of your work so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.